# How to determine if language pack in Lotus Notes Domino was successfully installed

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, lotus

one simple question. How can we determine if the language pack was successfully installed on the Lotus Domino Server 8.5.3?

The problem is that the web application, written in Xpages, uses built-in web controls, which are language specific. The administrators of the customer told us, that the language pack was installed, but the xpages built-in components are still in the english language.

On our servers we can see these built-in components in the right language. 
I would like to show them, that the language pack was not successfully installed. The argument, that we cannot see translated labels in that built-in components on web, is not sufficient.

Thanx

Comment: I don't think that language of XPages controls is determined by language packs but rather on the language setting of the browser. Try changing default language in the browser

Comment: See http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/Troubleshooting_the_IBM_Lotus_Domino_V8_language_pack.